# Substitute of ' Be + To + Verb '?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I've seen that the 'Be + to verb' is really formal. Although, is there a less formal way to say the same thing the 'Be + to verb' does?

Some examples:

> You **are to study** without watching tv.
>
> If I **were to be** the doctor, I would be unhappy;

Comment: Do you want to say "any doctor"? If so, it should be "a doctor" - "If I were **a** doctor, I would be unhappy"

Comment: Oh, no. It's more like "If I had to substitute and be the doctor, I would be unhappy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one can be rewritten in the imperative:

> Study and don’t watch tv.

Stronger imperative:

> Study and don’t you dare watch tv!

For the second one you can use *was* and drop *to be*:

> If I was the doctor, I’d be unhappy.

Not using the subjunctive (*were*) makes it [more informal](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2779/191178).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the construction is formal.

There are numerous alternatives:

> You **should / must / need to / ought to** study....

In the second example, just omit **to be**

> If I were the doctor......